# Rails Model and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

Sorry if this has been asked before but I've tried searching and can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

I have two tables, one is called users and has a user_id field, the second is called users_friends and only has two fields, user_id and friends_id

I've spent the entire day trying many different variations and cannot get it to pull back the friends as user objects like I'm expecting.

The entire contents of my UsersFriends model is

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
has_one :friends, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "id"
```

Thanks in advance,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a feeling that you do not understand how associations work. Please refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Also you might find reading github page and/or code of `acts_as_network` plugin quite helpful and inspiring for building your "friends" feature. Please have a look:
https://github.com/sjlombardo/acts_as_network